# having an empty page while calling a dynamic component angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I  try to call a dynamic component from another component but it showing me an empty page

This is the dynamic component.ts :

```
@Component({

selector: 'app-draw-linechart',
templateUrl: './draw-linechart.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./draw-linechart.component.css']
})
export class DrawLinechartComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(private productservice: ProductService) {}

ngOnInit() {
     this.PrepareData(); }     
PrepareData() {
  this.productservice.getProductsData(this.productHistoric).subscribe((data) => {
     this.historicproducts = data;
     console.log("historic products", this.historicproducts)
  });}
```

The dynamic component.html :

```
 <div class="container">
<mat-grid-list cols="1" rows="2" rowHeight="100px"  >
 <mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
        Line chart
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="prepareData()">Add Line chart</button>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

This is the other component where I called the dynamic component:

```
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver:ComponentFactoryResolver,private vf:ViewContainerRef){}
...
OnSubmit(){
 this.createComponent();}

createComponent(){
 let resolver = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DrawLinechartComponent);
 this.vf.createComponent(resolver);
```

}
Then I added the dynamic component in entryComponent of the module.ts:

```
entryComponents:[DrawLinechartComponent]
```

**In the console I got the correct data but I had an empty page ( I don't know why it not reading the html code )**

Comment: do you have a host to put the component in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, create a directive, you use this directive to any element that you want to be a container for your dynamic component:

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ad-host]',
})
export class AdDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

in your template:

```
<ng-template ad-host></ng-template>
```

in your component:

```
@ViewChild(AdDirective, {static: true}) adHost: AdDirective;
```

and then in your function:

```
const viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
viewContainerRef.clear();
const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

now your component will be created in the ng-template tag.

you can see a detailed example in [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: It's a nice solution but my problem is I had in the component where I must call the dynamic component a dialog form So now with your solution the dynamic component appear but inside the form ! This is the html I had  `<mat-dialog-content>    
  <form [formGroup]="lchartForm">...      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"
        (click)="OnSubmit();createComponent()" [mat-dialog-close]="true">Submit</button>          <ng-template ad-host></ng-template>`

Comment: oh. if you want to open a dialog you don't need to handle the creating of a component manually. mat dialog handles it for you.

Comment: In fact I want the dynamic component appear when I click on submit in the other component

Comment: ok just put the <ng-template ad-host></ng-template> in the parent component, then when the user submits and closes the dialog load the dynamic component;

Comment: what ever hteml you have in your dynamic template will be placed in <ng-template> so wherever it is the dynamic component will load there